# MVC3 change the url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url

We have a module to generate and store report in PDF format.

The url to get document for example like this:

```
https://domain.com/Document/GetDocument?documentId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

This url will return a document with name: `Document_UserName_Date`.

However, since there are browser can view PDF file like Chrome, the document will be view right in a tab of browser with above url.

So, when users try to save that document in their computers, the default file name(which get from url) is: `https___domain.com.pdf` instead of `Document_UserName_Date.pdf` as we expected.
So I'm thinking, if I can just changed the url into:

```
https://domain.com/Document/Document_UserName_Date.pdf
```

my problem will be solved.

Comment: Have you tried setting the content type to `application/pdf` in your response?

Comment: The user also likes to view the document with browsers.
That's why I'd like to change the url in the first place

Comment: Changing the url to have a '.pdf' extension alone might not solve your problem. You should set the right headers, as Darin mentions below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid the document being shown in the browser, but the user directly prompted to download it, you could use set the `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment`:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Document_UserName_Date.pdf"
```

This could be done by simply passing the filename as third argument to the File overload:

```
public ActionResult GetDocument(Guid documentId)
{
    byte[] document = GetDocument(documentId);
    return File(document, "application/pdf", "Document_UserName_Date.pdf");
}
```

---

UPDATE:

If you want the user to view the document inline in his browser then you could use routing and define the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ViewPdfRoute",
    "document/{id}/{name}.pdf",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "GetDocument" }
);
```

and in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult GetDocument(Guid id, string name)
{
    byte[] pdf = GetDocument(id);
    return File(pdf, "application/pdf");
}
```

And finally you could request a document like this:

```
http://domain.com/document/0DF7E254-0576-4BC0-8B05-34FC0F5246A2/document_username_date.pdf
```

Comment: The user also likes to view the document with browsers.That's why I'd like to change the url in the first place

Comment: I think Content Type and Content Disposition headers are the key. Athough, I have noted that some of the older browsers do not support inline viewing of PDF.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try it as the first thing to do at office tomorrow.